How can I display the information of the authenticated user on the index page after they login, using Thymeleaf and Spring Security?
I'm creating a spring boot and thymeleaf application. I want to display the email of the user that is logged in on the index page but I'm having no luck, it was working initially but not anymore.
This is the security configuration:
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final JwtAuthFilter JwtAuthFilter;
    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/index").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers(
                        "/login",
                        "/resources/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/fonts/**",
                        "/img/**")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/register")
                .permitAll()
//                .requestMatchers("/index").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
//                .addFilterBefore(JwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin(formLogin ->
                        formLogin
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .usernameParameter("email")
                                .passwordParameter("password")
//                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index", true)
                                .permitAll()
                ).sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                        sessionManagement
                                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) // Set to STATELESS for JWT-based authentication
                                .maximumSessions(1) // Limit to one session per user
                                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true) // Prevent new logins when maximum sessions reached
                                .expiredUrl("/login?expired") // Redirect URL for expired sessions
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
}


The user class:
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "client_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String companyName;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Appointment> appointments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Invoice> invoices;

    private boolean isAccountVerified;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}


And the CustomUserDetailsService:
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository UserRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = UserRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email: " + email);
        }

        // Convert PersistentSet to List
        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>(user.getRoles());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), getAuthorities(roles));
    }

//    public UserDetails loadByName(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException{
//        User user = UserRepository.findByName(name);
//        if (user == null){
//            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user with that name was found");
//        }
//    }

    public UserPrincipal getLoggedInUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return (UserPrincipal)authentication.getPrincipal();
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(List<Role> roles) {
        // You may implement role-based authentication here
//        return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}


I've implemented Spring Security for authentication in my Spring Boot application and configured Thymeleaf templates for rendering views. I've created a CustomUserDetailsService to load user details, and I've ensured that the /index endpoint requires authentication. However, I'm facing difficulties in displaying the information of the authenticated user on the index page after they login.
Update: My SecurityContextHolder is being set to anonymous: Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
